# Can I get access to all Photoshop.com slideshow features if I have Photoshop on my computer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

In Adobe's photoshop.com, there are different themes for creating slideshows. Some are premium features, only three of them are free.

Can I get all slideshow features if I buy a copy of Photoshop and install it on my computer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you can. Photohop standalone application and Photoshop.com are two totally different aspects of this Adobe product.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any Adobe product which allows to pick different pre-defined themes and create a slideshow for me?